# Memory warning with scroll view and over 5000 custom uiviews

Tags: ios, xcode, memory

I need help.

I have custom uitableviewcell with uiscrollview inside, I iterate over an nsarray and add custom uiviews (just subclassing drawrect: and do custom drawing) to my scrollview with addsubview: method, I refresh it every seconds and it reach me a memory warning and crash my app. My project is ARC, I can't call release. I thinks it's not the best solution to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: check for memory leaks using instruments..

Comment: thanks iShru, I use Instruments but it don't detect any memory leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finaly, I use my second approach (custom draw a single UIView and add it to my scrollview) thanks all for your help.

Comment: My attempt at reusable tiles (removing and adding to recycledTileSet and visibleTileSet) didn't work.  Only drawing a single UIView seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

simple. do not display 5000 views, or only create/keep the views you must present.

clear out what is not visible -or- if they are all visible at the same time, use a different approach to render.

Comment: Hi Justin, all my views are visible at the same time, my uiscrollview contain a grid of views (～5000) of 5x5 px with a specific color, I can't use the same approach, my another approach is to draw all the blocks in the same uiview and after add it to my scrollview but i don't like this.

Comment: @doc given what you describe, I would just use 1 UIView in this case.

Answer (score 1):

An improvement on Justin's answer, if there is a list of data then you are better off looking into how UITableView works.

If you are looking into building a game and having many small graphics on a screen at once you are better off using a major 2d rendering library like Cocos2d or Sparrow.

These are a couple of ways that you could implement Justin's idea, the former only draws (in other words hold in memory) as each row is used. The latter is built for handling lots of smaller images and performs better with high amounts of graphics by doing custom draw routines.

Comment: It's not a game Courtzie and it's a basic UI, my approach is maybe a bad idea but I don't understand why in this approach it's reach me a memory warning.

Answer (score 0):

If it only crashes after a few refreshes, that means you probably have a memory leak.

Chances are that you're using some CG stuff.  Core Graphics stuff isn't maintained by ARC, you need to do CG releases.  You can fix this by adding any missing releases, or you can generally use the UI equivalents if you're not doing graphics stuff in background threads.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Gordon, I use many CG stuffs to draw my custom view but nothing extraordinary, this is the drawing code of my custom UIView (ITPieceBlock):

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect { 
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 1.00);

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0.10, 0.10, 0.10, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, rect);




    if(self.status == 0)
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0.5, 0.5, 1.00, 1.0);
    else
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0.25, 0.25, 1.00, 1.0);

    CGContextFillRect(ctx, rect);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 1.0);
    CGContextStrokeRect(ctx, rect);

    [super drawRect:rect];
}
```

and the method who add This views to my UISCrollView:

```
- (void)processPieces:(NSString *)pieces withCount:(double)pieceCount{
    static int i, j, k;
    static NSData *buffer;

    static int offsetX = 10;
    static int offsetY = 10;
    static int blockW = 5;
    static int blockH = 5;
    static int x;
    static int y;
    CGRect rect = _scrollView.frame;

    [_piecesArray removeAllObjects];

    buffer = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:pieces];

    unsigned char* r = (unsigned char*)[buffer bytes];
    for (i=1; i<=[buffer length]; i++){
        j = (int) r[i];
        for (k=1; k<=8; k++){
            if (pieceCount == 8)
                break;
            if ((j & 0x80) != 0){
                [_piecesArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
            } else {
                [_piecesArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
            }

            j = j << 1;
            pieceCount--;
        }
    }

    x = offsetX;
    y = offsetY;

    if ([_piecesArray count] != 0)
        for (int i = 0; i< [_piecesArray count]; i++){
            if (i != 0) {
                if ((x + blockW) < rect.size.width - offsetX)
                    x += blockW;
                else {
                    x = offsetX;
                    y += blockH;
                }
            }

            ITPieceBlock * pieceBlock = [[ITPieceBlock alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, blockW, blockH)];
            [pieceBlock setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, blockW, blockH)];

            if ([[_piecesArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue] == 0)
                pieceBlock.status = 0;
            else
                pieceBlock.status = 1;

            [_scrollView addSubview:pieceBlock];
        }
    _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(280, y);
    [_scrollView flashScrollIndicators];
}
```